# Unable to understand error

Tags: c++, vector, mergesort

I have written a mergesort algo as follows but on compiling it I  get the following  ,which states 
**Expression: vector subscript out of range**

I dont understand why I am getting this error, plz point out the mistakes,I have coded this algo based on my understanding of the mergesort algorithm

As per my understanding I have coded a recursive function(mergesort), in which each time the array in question is divided in two parts left and right namely and then the left and right arrays are subdivided further till the point where there is only 1 element present in the subarrays once this stage arrives the merge function is called to sort the partitioned arrays and merge it to the original array from which the arrays were partitioned and the recursion goes a step backward in the recursion tree

Here is the source code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Soham
{
    vector<int> v;
public:
    Soham();
    void merge(vector<int> &, vector<int> & ,vector<int> &);
    void mergesort(vector<int> &);
};
Soham::Soham()
{
    int no;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> no;
        v.push_back(no);
    }
    mergesort(v);
    cout << "result" << endl;
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << " ";
}
void Soham::mergesort(vector<int> &v)
{
    if (v.size() < 2)
        return;
    else
    {
        vector<int>left, right; 
        if (v.size() % 2 == 0)//if input size is even
        {
            auto it = v.begin() + (v.size() / 2);
            left.assign(v.begin(),it);
            right.assign(it, v.end());
        }
        else// if input size is odd
        {
            auto it = v.begin() + (v.size() / 2);
            left.assign(v.begin(),next(it));
            right.assign(next(it), v.end());
        }
        mergesort(left);
        mergesort(right);
        merge(left, right,v);
    }
}
void Soham::merge(vector<int> &temp_left, vector<int> &temp_right,vector<int> &temp_main)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i<= temp_left.size() && j <= temp_right.size())
    {
        if (temp_left[i] <= temp_right[j])
        {
            temp_main[k] = temp_left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp_main[k]=temp_right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= temp_left.size())
    {
        temp_main[k]=temp_left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j <= temp_right.size())
    {
        temp_main[k]=temp_right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Soham a;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks For Help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please put any error messages *in* the question, *verbatim* and as text - *not* behind links or as images.

Comment: How about Pressing the Retry and open the debugger to see where the out-of-bounds access occurred?

Comment: edited as per requested @JesperJuhl

Comment: Not able to find it while debugging @ArtemyVysotsky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (i <= temp_left.size())
```

When you access vector at index size() you will get your out-of-bounds access

Comment: Note that you can use at() instead of [] so it will throw exception in cse of incorrect index temp_main.at(k) = temp_left.at(i)